# how to make python3.3 gui window fixed sizes?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-3.3

as for the question mentioned, i cant find any code which can fixed the gui window and positions of all the labels, buttons etc..

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox

class Menu:
    def __init__(self):

        self.main = tkinter.Tk(height = 200, width = 400)

        self.position = tkinter.Label(self.main, text = '123',\
                                      bg = 'Purple',\
                                      height = 2, width = 8)
        self.position.place(height=50, width= 100)

        self.position.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

gui = Menu()
```

for this, i can only do the sizing of the label, not the position and the size of the main window. 
it gives this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Saves\Label position.py", line 18, in <module>
    gui = Menu()
  File "C:\Python33\Saves\Label position.py", line 7, in __init__
    self.main = tkinter.Tk(height = 200, width = 400)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'height'
```

Comment: Are you _certain_ you want to specify the size? The vast majority of GUIs are better of when they are allowed to be their natural size. Or, are you just experimenting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you cannot set the width and height of the Tk element in the constructor. However, you can use the `geometry` method:

```
self.main = tkinter.Tk()
self.main.geometry("400x200")
```

Comment: Hi, it worked for the sizing of main window, but how do i do the positioning of the widgets? the .place does not seems to work either.

Comment: @user2294001 Don't use different geometry managers (`pack` and `place`) in the same window. If you have a simple layout, `pack` with the appropiate padding may be enough.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `minsize` and `maxsize` methods to set the size of the window. The following code will make a fixed size window. Of course, you can skip one of them to give your user the option to resize the window in any one direction.

```
top = tkinter.Tk()
top.minsize(width=300, height=300)
top.maxsize(width=300, height=300)
```

Answer (score 1):

The right method to do this is to write this line after your window declaration :

`{yourwindow}.resizable(width = False, height = False)`

Source :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SVW0ofsBKCU

Answer (score 0):

You can use the resizable function.

```
root = Tk()
root.title('TITLE')
root.resizable(0, 0)
```